# TypeError: add_log() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given Not obvious

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jerem\Source\Repos\ets-ws\python\shot_caller.py", line 73, in add_log
    add_log(cursor, current_log)
TypeError: add_log() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is my code samples

Main:

```
cursor = dev_db_connection()
log_queue = queue.Queue()

    def add_log(cursor):
            while True:
                if log_queue.empty() == False:
                    current_log = log_queue.get()
                    add_log(cursor, current_log)
```

SQL lib:

```
def add_log(cursor, current_log):
    return sql_query(cursor, """SQL query string""")
```

Couple notes:

`sql_query()` does work properly, it seems to be breaking in the `add_log()` function.

This is being put into a thread and the data being put into the queue is a tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

I can answer any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same name in both `Main` and `SQL lib`.

Main:

```
...
log_queue = queue.Queue()

    def add_log(cursor):  # <= Here is an "add_log".
...
```

SQL lib:

```
def add_log(cursor, current_log):  # <= Here is another one.
    return sql_query(cursor, """SQL query string""")
```

So interpreter try to use the closest one which is in `Main`.